# How to use this chapter style such that it takes up less space?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I like the box chapter style from here: http://hstuart.dk/2007/05/21/styling-the-chapter/

Here is a MWE based on this style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz, blindtext}
\makechapterstyle{box}{
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{
    \flushright
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushright\chaptitlefont##1}
}
\chapterstyle{box}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Fancy chapter with TikZ}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to eliminate some of the white space indicated by 1 and 2 (so above and below the box, but mostly above the box). Of course there should be a bit of white space, but I don't want the chapter headings to take up much space so it should be rather small. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Bonus question: is it possible to do all while allowing me to use the `report` class (I don't know what possible disadvantages the `memoir` class could bring me later on)?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: The `memoir` class has *many* more features than `report`; use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you are.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz, blindtext,showframe}  %% blindtext,showframe just for demo
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
\newcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
\newcommand{\mybox}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \draw[color=white,font=\chapnumfont] (1cm,1cm) node {\thechapter};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{\filleft\mybox}{20pt}{\filleft\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Fancy chapter with TikZ}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Adjust values in `\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` which is `\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}` by default, I have made them all zero.

[image]

The `20pt` in `...\mybox}{20pt}...` in `\titleformat` is the vertical space between chapter number and title. Adjust if you want.

Comment: The OP is using `memoir`.

Comment: @egreg I think you missed the bonus question `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I am of the impression that the OP wants to use report class

Comment: Thanks a lot! To clarify: I was using the `report` class till I stumbled upon this chapter style that used the memoir class. I know little of the features of the `memoir` class, so that's why I thought it might be best to stick to what I have. Or which class would you say is best?

Comment: @texfan `memoir` has lot of features. But all that can be had with `report` class too by yourself. That is the only difference. Choice is yours. Personally I don't use `memoir`. There are also koma classes like `scrbook` etc which have features too just for your information.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the specific parameters of `memoir`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz, blindtext,showframe}
\makechapterstyle{box}{%
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}% was 50pt
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{20pt}%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{20pt}% was 40pt
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \flushright
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushright\chaptitlefont##1}%
}

\chapterstyle{box}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Fancy chapter with TikZ}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I used `showframe` to make apparent the bounding boxes of the various page parts.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! You mentioned in the comments that the `memoir` class has much more features. I don't know much about it but: can I safely start using it for my project without missing features later on? Also, would there be significant upsides of using it or could I just as well stick to the report class?

Comment: @texfan Don't worry about using `memoir`. You *can* use its advanced features, but you're not forced to.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I will keep using the `memoir` class because in your answer it seems simpler to adjust the space fully to my liking. I will however accept Harish Kumar's answer because he answered the bonus question that I initially posed. I hope you understand :/.